# ListView not scrolling when items added pro-grammatically

Tags: winforms

I have a `listView` which I add a number of buttons to in a for loop. However the `listView` isn't `scrollable` even if I set it to be `scrollable`. I'm not sure why this is happening. I'm simply adding a button every time I enter the for loop however once there is too many buttons to view on the `listview` no scroll bar appears. My code is as follows.

```
                ListViewTemplates.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None
                For i As Integer = 1 To level3Cat.Count

                    counter = i Mod 2
                    If counter = 0 Then
                        Dim picture As Button = New Button()
                        picture.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(165, topForNextControl)
                        picture.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(90, layoutTemplateHeight)
                        picture.TabStop = False
                        picture.BackgroundImageLayout = BackgroundImageLayout.Stretch
                        picture.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.XButton
                        ListViewTemplates.Controls.Add(picture)
                        topForNextControl += layoutTemplateHeight + HeighScaleFactor

                    Else


                        Dim picture As Button = New Button()
                        picture.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(35, topForNextControl)
                        picture.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(90, layoutTemplateHeight)
                        picture.TabStop = False
                        picture.BackgroundImageLayout = BackgroundImageLayout.Stretch
                        picture.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.XButton
                        ListViewTemplates.Controls.Add(picture)
                    End If
                    ListViewTemplates.Scrollable = True
                    ListViewTemplates.View = View.Details

                    counter += 1

                Next
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the scrollable after the loop?

Comment: A ListView is **not** a standard container like a Panel...are you trying to add Buttons to each row maybe?  If so, search for that.  Perhaps you should be using a DataGrid instead?  Give more details...